# How to extract a value inside href= and title and description values from hyperlinkable image divs in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I got an HTML string as (var code); I want to extract all values of sid=(example:12345) inside href and title(example: Star Album) and episode number (example:episode 4) but i am wondering how I can do that in JavaScript and have all sid, title and episode number values in array so i can construct hyperlinks ?

Note: initial value of $code is blocks of div like example below:

```
<td width=120 valign="top">                     <div style="height:135px;
    border:1px solid #BBBBBB; background:#BBBBBB; margin-left:2px;
    text-align:center; ">
                    <a href="/now/episodes.php?name=path&id=4000&sid=12345&page=0"><img
    border="0" src="http://www.somesite.com/1234.jpg" width="150"
    height="83"></a><br>
                        <font face="Tahoma" size="2"><b>Star Album</b><br/>
                            episode 4
                        </font>             </div>


        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/enolak/1/)

```
var code = '<td width=120 valign="top"><div style="height:135px;border:1px solid #BBBBBB; background:#BBBBBB; margin-left:2px;text-align:center;"><a href="/now/episodes.php?name=path&id=4000&sid=12345&page=0"><img border="0" src="http://www.somesite.com/1234.jpg" width="150" height="83"></a><br><font face="Tahoma" size="2"><b>Star Album</b><br/>episode 4</font></div></td>';
function getDetails(html){
    var div = $('<div></div>')
    div.html(html);
    var count=0;
    var arr = [];
    div.find('a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href = href.substring(href.indexOf('sid=')+4, href.indexOf('&page='));

        var title = $(this).parent().find('b').eq(count++).text();
        arr.push({"sid" : href , "title": title});
    });
    return arr;
}

console.log(getDetails(code));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .could you tell me how to print those values . i run the above code nothing got printed.Forthermore, does your code deals with multiple blocks of divs too ?

Comment: well your solution only deals with one block of div that is in one line. I tried it with multiple div blocks and it failed Furthermore it doesnot output this value :episode 4 . Is there away to make your code work with multiple blocks of divs that are not all in one line ?